# How to get a file name for a directory with a specific substring title

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get to read all lines from a file into a directory that has a title with a specific substring.

I need everything in just one line of code, That's why I'm trying to use LINQ.

```
File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetFiles(Path).Select(i=>  i.Where(i.Contains("mystring")) );
```

But the compiler doesn't like it - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetFiles(Path).First(i => i.Contains("mystring")))`

Answer (score 0):

To get all files with some string in title use that query:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path).Where(f => f.Contains("mystring").ToList())
```

You can change `ToList()` with `First()` to get only the first one instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it handles possible exceptions.

```
string fileContent = string.Empty;
var fileName = Directory.GetFiles(Path).Where(i => i.Contains("mystring")).FirstOrDefault();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
  fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```